# Attaching double click event to a label

Tags: events, gtk, signals

How can I attach a "clicked" event to a label? I tried GtkEventBox but had no luck with it.

Answer (score 12):

Connect to the `button-press-event` signal on the EventBox.

Comment: Why button press? Thread creator talks about mouse click, not button press

Comment: Oh ny bet. It appears button press means mouse button. Sorry

Comment: In my testing, Labels specifically appeared to consume `button-press-event`; I had no trouble using the signal on other widgets;  :\ Weird.Other comments suggest a Gtk.EventBox is necessary for labels.

Answer (score 11):

Gtk# differentiates between Widgets and 'Containers'. Most widgets placed on a Gtk# form will NOT receive mouse click events. In order to receive a mouse event you need to place the widget inside a specific container - like EventBox:

1. Add an EventBox containter to your form. You can place it behind other Widgets or since it is not visible, unless you specifically select it to be (or change its background color).
2. Put your label widget inside this EventBox. Notice that the label will get the shape and size of the EventBox.
3. Add to this EventBox the signal 'ButtonPressEvent' out of the "Common Widget Signals".

If you need to identify the button that was clicked while handling this event, use the uint value in: args.Event.Button typically '1' will be the left mouse button, '2' the center button and '3' the right button ('2' might be also when both left and right buttons are clicked).

Answer (score 4):

It seems you don't need EventBox at all: Since the problem is that labels don't have any associated X11 window, just give it one with `set_has_window(True)`! The following works for me:

```
    self.label = Gtk.Label()
    self.label.set_has_window(True)
    self.label.set_events(Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK)
    self.label.connect("button-press-event", self.click_label)
```

The [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-has-window) says it should only be used for implementing widgets - but hey, it works. Who cares about "should"?

Answer (score 2):

**2019-04-17 Update:**

ptomato here is right, `GtkLabel` is one of the exceptions that indeed requires an eventbox, so you should connect to the `button-press-event` signal of the eventbox. For other widgets, the set/add events APIs in my original answer  should be still relevant.

**Original (wrong) answer:**

Connect to the button-press-event signal, but directly on the GtkLabel. I'd say you don't need an eventbox here, as GtkLabel already inherits this signal from GtkWidget. To enable the GtkLabel to receive those events, you need first to call [gtk_widget_set_events](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-events) or [gtk_widget_add_events](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-add-events), and add the sensitivity to the [GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Events.html#GdkEventMask) event.

Comment: Not all GTK widgets can receive events. `GtkLabel` is one of those, which need to be wrapped in an event box. See for example this question from the PyGTK FAQ: http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?query=eventbox&querytype=simple&req=search

Comment: The bit about the GDK mask might be useful for other widgets, however.